# Why is this JS function returning the wrong date?

Tags: javascript, json, date

I am using a JS function to read from a JSON formatted like so:

```
{
  "metrics": {
"2018-12-28 12:00:00": {
  "20": 19
},
"2018-12-28 13:00:00": {
  "20": 76
},
"2018-12-28 14:00:00": {
  "20": 39
 }
```

}
}

From this file I am creating a new object with the date in "2018-12-28" format and the number of "20". Here is the function:

```
let op = {}
  for(let key in names){
    let temp = new Date(key);
    let fullDate = temp.getFullYear()+'-'+temp.getMonth()+'-'+temp.getDate();
    if(op[fullDate]){
      for(let val in names[key])
      {
        if(op[fullDate][val])
         op[fullDate][val] += names[key][val]
        else op[fullDate][val] = names[key][val]
      }
    } else {
      op[fullDate] = {...names[key]};
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the function is outputting the date a month behind ("2018-11-28" as opposed to "2018-12-28") and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Count starting at 0 not at 1?

Comment: Note that in Safari, `new Date("2018-12-28 12:00:00")` produces an invalid Date. It is strongly recommended to not use the built-in parser.

Answer (score 2):

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Months are 0 based, so January is 0 and December is 11.

Answer (score 2):

`getMonth()` is zero-based. You should just add 1 to get the desired result.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Yes, adding +1 solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Mark as correct please :)